# Choppy sound and recording in Audacity

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, audacity

I have an Audacity project with around 25 tracks, absolutely no overlap between them. I'm trying to record from a microphone with some overlap and the playback gets really chopped while recording and probably the recording is broken as well.

his is running on a Ubuntu 9.10 box that has 3GB of RAM and an Intel Core 2 Duo CPU (1.83GHz).

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you adjust an audio buffer/latency setting?  This will make the CPU work less, but it will take longer to get audio in and out of the audio interface.

Comment: How do I change the buffer/latency?

Comment: Have you tried poking around any preference areas in the application?  I don't have it in front of me now.

Comment: Preferences > Audio I/O > Audio to buffer

That will most likely be it.  Put a value of 512 in there.  Double it if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered that problem on a slightly less powerful machine: trying to record another track when there are some already in the project resulted in somewhat interrupted sound. This is some performance issue in Audacity; I solved it by creating a new project for each track I was recording and then merging them afterwise. Sorry, no better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem recording audio playback from qsynth with JACK, the audio always got chopped in fixed intervals.

The solution was to go in *Edit → Preferences... → Recording* and set Latency Correction to `0`.